# Frontend implementation of JIRA like Advanced Search in NextJs to handle multi selects and validate it

Tags: reactjs, search, jira, multi-select, jql

I am in process of writing a similar Advanced Search like JIRA in Next Js. On initial click i am showing the list of users on click showing subsequent lists, but at end the search query becomes clumsy as i am making each tag separately. Is there any reference to the Atlassian's JIRA Search ? That would be of great help...

I tried handling each tag on click and added handlers for each operation but at the end the searched text is behaving as fixed tags.